# calling a function from two different pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

i made a react web app , it should hide the navigation bar on login page then it should reappear after a successful login in all other other pages. The way i made the header hidden in login page is by making a function  , but the login button is located in another page (Authen.js) and the function is located in App.js my problem is that i can't call the function from the first page to the other .

```
./src/App.js
  Line 69:  'operation' is not defined  no-undef 

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Authen from './Pages/Authen'
import Home from './Pages/Home';
import secondpage from './Pages/secondpage';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';
var firebase = require('firebase');


class App extends Component {
      constructor(props){
          super(props);

          this.state = {
          ShowMe:false
          };
        }

         operation(){
          this.setState({
            ShowMe:true
          })
        }

    render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <Router >
          <div>
            <div>
            {
              this.state.ShowMe?
              <ul>


                <li><Link to="/Home">Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/secondpage">secondpage</Link></li>
              </ul>
              :null
            }

          </div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Authen}/>
          <Route path="/Home" component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/secondpage" component={secondpage}/>
          </div>
        </Router>
    </div>
      );
    }
  }
export default App;
```

the login page :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import {operation} from '../App'
var firebase = require('firebase');

class Authen extends React.Component {


    Login = () => {
                //login method
    const email = this.refs.email.value;
    const password = this.refs.password.value;
    console.log(email,password);

    const auth = firebase.auth();

    const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);


    promise.catch(e =>{
      var err = e.message;
      console.log(err);
      this.setState({err: err});
    });
    //gets user uid
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    console.log(user.uid);
 this.props.history.push('/Home');
 operation();
  }
});
}


constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        err:''
    };
    this.Login = this.Login.bind(this);
  }
  render(){
    return(
        <div className="login_div">
          <div  className="main-div">
   <h3>N.N.NASSAR</h3>
    <input ref="email" type="email" placeholder="Email..." id="email_field" />
    <input ref="password" type="password" placeholder="Password..." id="password_field" />
    <p>{this.state.err}</p>
     <button onClick={() => this.Login() || this.operation()} id="Login"> Login </button>
    <button onClick={this.signup}>Sign Up</button>
  </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Authen);
```

thank you for your time :)

Comment: ..and what is your question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: jonathan my problem is that i can't use the fucntion located in App.js where i want and that is in Auth.js

Comment: The use of punctuation is really quite helpful for adult readers who are attempting to assist you. Do you think you can help with that?

Comment: sorry guys my english and my coding aint that good but i am trying my best :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to call the 'operation' method of App from another component, and the reason you want to do that is because you want to set App's state from both App and from the other component.

One simple way to do it is by using redux and accessing the global state in the redux store, where you will save the state that you want to updare from both components.

Comment: By default Showme is false so i want to set it to true

Comment: Right, but you want to accessbit from App and modify it in Authen... redux will enable you to do this. Not too difficult to implement. There are many simple examples showing how to use redux, and it is worth learning because it is very useful for many applications.